# Search for a keyword in the files present in Artifactory 4

Tags: search, artifactory, keyword

I have JFrog Artifactory 4.14. I want to search for particular keywords in the files present in Artifactory by providing extension details.

For example, I want to search the keyword "Azure" in all ".properties" and ".tf" file present in my JFrog Artifactory. How could we perform such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no supported way to directly search the contents of a file via Artifactory toolings.
I recommend to use the jfrog cli to download the properties files. Then to script a search and match the findings with the "detailed summary" to find them on the instance again.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles

You may be limited in your cli options due to the old version of Artifactory you are running.

[image: jfrogcli download example screenshot]

Comment: If im logging into my Linux server where my Artifactory is installed, how can we search a keyword in the files present inside the particular extension ? Any inputs please ?